# Does the ACTION_VIEW intent no longer work on Android 13?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to install an update to my application that has been downloaded, the code below works if

```
compileSdkVersion = 28
minSdkVersion = 26
targetSdkVersion = 28
```

And it doesn't work in

```
compileSdkVersion = 33
minSdkVersion = 28
targetSdkVersion = 33
```

```
private fun Context.openNewVersion(location: String) {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.setDataAndType(
            getUriFromFile(location),
            "application/vnd.android.package-archive"
        )
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        startActivity(intent)
}
```

Do you really have to not use ACTION_VIEW on Android 13? is there another way on android 13?

Comment: What is getUriFromFile() ?

Comment: What is location?

Comment: What means 'it does not work'?

Comment: What do you want with ACTION_VIEW?

Comment: What should happen?

Comment: What happens instead?

Comment: sorry for the incomplete question, in essence I asked if ACTION_VIEW still works on android 13 and I have found the answer

Comment: Your question was wrong as it still works of course but not for installing packages.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ACTION_VIEW` to install apps has been out of favor for quite some time, so it would not surprise me if there are problems.

`PackageInstaller` has been the recommended solution for years. I walk through how to use `PackageInstaller` in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Q/pages/chap-pkg-001.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Q/).